# Last modification time reported by stat() changes depending on daylight savings time

Tags: windows, perl

The last modification time of my file is changing by 3600 seconds (one hour) depending on my system's daylight savings time setting. The documentation for `stat` states that mtime is measured in seconds since the epoch. As such, mtime should not depend on DST.

This is causing my application to detect/report files as different when it shouldn't.

Answer (score 6):

The behavior described is a Windows "feature" (or [deliberate bug](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/190315) depending on your point of view) that affects NTFS filesystems. The behavior is caused by the implementation of the `stat` function in Microsoft's C runtime and inherited by perl.

The [Win32::UTCFileTime](http://search.cpan.org/perldoc/Win32::UTCFileTime) module provides replacements for the built-in `stat`, `lstat`, and `utime` functions that work around the behavior in Windows. The module's documentation also contains a in-depth description of the problem and why it's implemented the way it is.